# Route group resource controller only index and create method is working on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Foo controller:

```
class FooController extends Controller {

  public function index() {
      return 'Index method';
  }

  public function create(){
      return 'Create method';
  }

  public function show($id){
      return 'show method with parameter: ' . $id;
  }

  public function edit($id) {}
  public function update($id){}
  etc..

}
```

Routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo'], function()
{
  // some get, post or resource controller here..

  Route::resource('/', 'FooController');
}
```

> URI: example.dev:8000/foo 
> *Index method*
>
> URI: example.dev:8000/foo/create 
> *Create method*
>
> URI: example.dev:8000/foo/1 
> *NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:*
>
> URI: example.dev:8000/foo/1/edit 
> *NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:*
>
> etc..

My app routes

```
[Method] | [URI] | [Name] | [Action]

GET|HEAD| foo| foo..index| App\Http\Controllers\FooController@index
GET|HEAD| foo/create| foo..create| App\Http\Controllers\FooController@create
POST| foo| foo..store| App\Http\Controllers\FooController@store
GET|HEAD| foo/{}| foo..show| App\Http\Controllers\FooController@show
GET|HEAD| foo/{}/edit| foo..edit| App\Http\Controllers\FooController@edit
PUT| foo/{}| foo..update| App\Http\Controllers\FooController@update
PATCH| foo/{}|| App\Http\Controllers\FooController@update
DELETE| foo/{}| foo..destroy| App\Http\Controllers\FooController@destroy
```

What is wrong with my code? Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URI: example.dev:8000/foo/1
```

this url parsed like `URI: example.dev:8000/1`

you have to do this way

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo'], function()
{
  // some get, post or resource controller here..

  Route::resource('bar', 'FooController');
}
```

then URI: `example.dev:8000/foo/bar/1` will work